# Not able to drag and drop element in firefox and chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, drag-and-drop

Not able to drag and drop element in firefox, throws "`buttondown`" timeout, even though the target element is visible,enable,displayed

On the Chrome, the code gets executed without exception but action is not performed.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(BrowserClass.WebDriver);

var src = BrowserClass.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'box-padding')]/ul/li[11]/div/div/div"));
var dest = BrowserClass.WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[id*='row-cxs-control-2']>div>div>div>div>div:nth-child(1)>div"));       

actions.ClickAndHold(src);
try {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    var s = e.StackTrace;
}
actions.MoveToElement(dest).Release(dest).Build();
actions.Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect way of dragging may be a cause. Change

```
actions.MoveToElement(dest).Release(dest).Build(); //seems incorrect to release `dest` here
actions.Perform();
```

to either of these :

```
actions.DragAndDrop(src,dest).Build().Perform();
```

Or

```
actions.ClickAndHold(src).MoveToElement(dest).Release().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Tried both the option but when i perform 
actions.ClickAndHold(src).build.perform , it still throws error as "buttondown timed out". Strac trace is as follows:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7056/hub/session/a6e62368-db91-4243-9183-dba6b4919ecd/buttondown timed out after 60 seconds.
  Source=WebDriver

Comment: It would be good if you perform all the actions `ClickAndHold` , `MoveToElement` , `Release` simultaneously